# Не отображается изображение и кнопка в приложении PyQt6, как исправить?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt6

Доброго времени суток!

Есть небольшая проблема: в приложении PyQt6 вызывается функция (self.win), которая создаёт и накладывает изображение на само приложение и вызывает другую функцию (self.preparation_end_game), которая создаёт кнопку. Но если вызывать self.win внутри слота, реагирующего на нажатие кнопки, то ни изображение, ни кнопка не отображаются, хотя обе функции отрабатывают.

Код self.win:

```
def win(self):
    self.image_end_game = QLabel(self)
    self.image_end_game.setPixmap(QPixmap(r'other_files\win_image.png'))
    self.image_end_game.setGeometry(self.width() // 2 - 250, self.height() // 2 - 250, 500, 500)
    self.preparation_end_game()
```

Код self.preparation_end_game:

```
def preparation_end_game(self):
    self.button_end = QPushButton(self)
    self.button_end.setText('End game')
    self.button_end.setGeometry(0, 0, 80, 80)
    self.button_end.clicked.connect(self.end_game)
```

Заранее благодарю

Comment: Jagor, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: `self.image_end_game.show()` в конце. Для кнопки тоже самое.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Спасибо большое, помогло!